# C++ passing variables in classes and getting logical errors

Tags: c++, class, logic

Here is the prompt I haven't gotten to all of it yet though:

Implement a class  named  GasPump that will be used to model a pump at a gas station.
A GasPump object  should be able to perform the following tasks:
- Display the amount of gas dispensed
- Display the total amount charged for the amount of gas dispensed
- Set the cost per gallon on gas
- Display the cost per gallon of gas
- Reset the amount of gas dispensed and amount charged before each new usage
- Keep track of the amount of gas dispensed and the total charge

When implementing the GasPump class , you should assume  that the gas pump dispenses
.10 gallons of gas per second. Write a test program  in main() that prompts the user 
to enter the cost per gallon of gas and how many seconds they want to pump gas for.
Then, display the number of gallons of gas pumped, the cost per gallon of gas, and
the total cost of the gas.

I am having problems calculating the amount paid and keep getting logical errors. As this code stands it will compile but it gives garbage for a calculation for amount charged.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class GasPump{
    public:
            void setCostPerGallon(double cpg){
                    costPerGallon = cpg;
            }

            double getCostPerGallon(){
                    return costPerGallon;
            }
            void setAmountDispensed(int seconds){
                    const double dispense = 0.10;
                    sec = seconds;
                    amountDispensed = dispense * sec;
            }

            int getAmountDispensed(){
                    return amountDispensed;
            }
//here is the function I am having problems with, at least I think.
            void setAmountCharged(double costPerGallon, double     amountDispensed){
                    amountCharged = costPerGallon * amountDispensed;
            }

            double getAmountCharged(){
                    return amountCharged;
            }

    private:
            double costPerGallon;
            int sec;
            double amountCharged, amountDispensed;
};

int main() {
    double cpg = 0.0;
    int seconds = 0;
    GasPump pump;

    cout << "Enter the cost per gallon of gas:";
    cin  >> cpg;
    while(cpg <= 0.0) {
        cout << "Enter a value greater than 0:";
        cin  >> cpg;
    }
    pump.setCostPerGallon(cpg);

    cout << "Enter the amount of seconds you want to pump gas for:";
    cin  >> seconds;
    while(seconds <= 0.0) {
        cout << "Enter a value greater than 0:";
        cin  >> seconds;
    }
    pump.setAmountDispensed(seconds);

    cout << "The gas pump dispensed " << pump.getAmountDispensed() << " gallons of gas." << endl
         << "At $" << pump.getCostPerGallon() << " per gallon, your total is $"
         << fixed << setprecision(2) << pump.getAmountCharged() << "." << endl;

    return 0;
```

Comment: Elaborate about your _logic errors_ please. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Sorry forgot to post the output as follows: 
Enter the cost per gallon of gas:4.25
Enter the amount of seconds you want to pump gas for:342
The gas pump dispensed 34 gallons of gas.
At $4.25 per gallon, your total is $-0.00.

Comment: "Keep getting logical errors" isn't a valid problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `pump.setAmountCharged(...)`, so the member variable `amountCharged` is whatever the compiler decided to initialize it to when you instantiated `pump` (typically 0);

To fix this, either get rid of the member variable `amountCharged` and do the calculation for the amount when `getAmountCharged` is called, or call `setAmountCharged` appropriately before calling `getAmountCharged`.

Here's the first solution:

```
class GasPump {
    ...
    double getAmountCharged() {
        return costPerGallon * amountDispensed;
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: I got rid of the 'amountCharged' and used the solution you posted but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Meant to use `amountDispensed` like in your original code as opposed to `sec`. Here's a full [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7de06135596c5c01) with the complete solution.